# applying multiple effect to opencv live stream

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi3

I want to write a script on raspberry with opencv and python that can apply effect to livestream video,
every thing is working but the problem is that i cant apply clahe to stream when it is in gray scale mode, when stream is not grayscale I can apply clahe but when i change it to grayscale clahe doesnt work.
here is my code:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
gray_flag=True
cl_flag = False

def clahe():

    global frame
    clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(20, tileGridSize=(8,8))  
    lab = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB) 
    l, a, b = cv2.split(lab)  
    l2 = clahe.apply(l)  
    lab = cv2.merge((l2,a,b))  
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(lab, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)

while True:
    was_pressed = False
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    if c & 0xFF == ord('h'):
        if not gray_flag:
            gray_flag = True        
        else:
            gray_flag = False

    elif c & 0xFF == ord('d'):
        if not cl_flag:
            cl_flag = True
        else:
            cl_flag = False

    if gray_flag:    
        if cl_flag:
            clahe()
        else:
            pass
        cv2.imshow('a', gray)

    else:
        if cl_flag:
            clahe()
        else:
            pass
        cv2.imshow('a', frame)
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

does anybody know how can I apply clahe in both grayscale and colored?

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because they don't have the same amount of channels so you can't convert from grayscale to clahe